# DataTables Jquery Ajax Object not finding array columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I'm trying to use jquery.dataTables with an Ajax data source to pull json data into a html table.

I'm facing an issue where it's not able to find the data I'm looking for in the JSON response and I'm struggling to find where my issue lies. I'm getting an undefined error as it's not able to match the data columns I requested.

In the Snipped-I removed the URL but here's a sample of the object structure returned.

```
{
    "success": true,
    "result": [
        {
            "type": "gift",
            "name": "Gift",
            "rewards": [
                {
                    "name": "Item Name",
                    "image_url": "https://xxx.jpg",
                    "minimum_display_price": "500+ bucks",
                    "description": {
                        "text": "text here",
                        "html": "html here"
                    },
                    "disclaimer_html": "disclaimer",
                    "warning": null,
                    "denominations": [
                        {
                            "id": "5ca1737f1sdasdsadsad2cb5f004cc0d564",
                            "name": "Name",
                            "price": 500,
                            "display_price": "500",
                            "available": true
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "ajax": "myurlishere",
        "columns": [ 
            { "result[0]": "name" }
            //{ "result": "rewards.name"}
            // {"data": "name"}
            
        ]
    } );
} );
```

```html
<script language="JavaScript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.2/js/buttons.colVis.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.2/js/buttons.print.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.2/js/buttons.bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/2.5.0/jszip.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">

        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                
                
                
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                
                
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have some nested data objects and while it might be possible to deal with this directly within DataTable it's likely easier to pre-process the data before handing it off to DataTable for rendering. This would convert your nested data into a flat array of reward objects, which should make rendering it easier.

```
(async function() {
    const rawData = await fetch("your_url").then(data => data.json());
    const finalData = rawData.result.map(category => category.rewards).flat(1);
    $("#example").DataTable({
        data: finalData,
        columns: [{ data: "name" }]
    });
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be you need to change your code , just check following way,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#example').DataTable( {
    "ajax": "myurlishere",
    "columns": [
        { "data": "name" },
        { "data": "rewards[, ].name" },
        { "data": "rewards[, ].image_url" },
        { "data": "rewards[, ].description.text" },
        { "data": "rewards[, ].denominations[,].name" },

    ]
} );
```

} );

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm still getting an error:
`jquery.min.js:formatted:1532 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`
I've tried using an Ajax URL and also objects.txt as a local file to ensure there's no issue with the url

Comment: That your error says conflicting the js files on application , check once your js file's order and is it loading correctly or not

Comment: Even if I strip the <head> down to just Jquery.js and jquery.datatables.js, it gives the same error
`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script><script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script></head>`